Why does the application of a magnetic field lead to non-thermodynamic equilibrium effects
There is a two-dimensional container filled with $N$ gas atoms, each with an electric charge $q$ and mass $m$. A magnetic field is gradually applied to this system in the direction perpendicular to the plane of the paper until the magnetic flux density reaches $B$. The final distribution of the system is non-thermodynamic equilibrium.
The questions are:

Why does the application of a magnetic field, an operation analogous to the evolution of the Hamiltonian, lead to non-thermodynamic equilibrium effects?

Are there any alternative methods to reach the same conclusion?


The following:

Consider the Liouville Equation:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}+\dot{r}\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}+\dot{\theta}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}+\dot{p}_r\frac{\partial f}{\partial p_r}+\dot{p}_{\theta}\frac{\partial f}{\partial p_\theta}=0
\end{equation}
The Hamiltonian is given as:
\begin{equation}
H=\frac{p_r^2}{2m}+\frac{(p_\theta-\frac{1}{2}Bqr^2)^2}{2mr^2}
\end{equation}
thus
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}+\frac{p_r}{m}\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}+(\frac{p_\theta^2}{mr^3}-\frac{B^2q^2}{4m}r)\frac{\partial f}{\partial p_r}=0
\end{equation}
let $\dot{B}$ seem to be $0$. And thermodynamic equilibrium condition at the beginning.
\begin{equation}
f=Ae^{-\beta(\frac{p_r^2+p_\theta^2/r^2}{2m}+\frac{B^2q^2}{8m}r^2)}
\end{equation}

In Classical Statistical Mechanics, introducing a magnetic field in a charged particle system does not modify the thermodynamic properties (Bohr–Van Leeuwen theorem). On what basis not only there should be an effect but it would be of getting the system out of equilibrium?

@giorgiop that's what i ask.The induced electric field drives the system into a vortex state, but the thermodynamic imbalance is unexpected.

Well if we need to figure out a reason why this system does not reach thermodynamic equilibrium, I would say that it stop to be ergodic, since all particles are rotating in different circles and not exploring the whole sphere hypersphere in phase space anymore.

It is inconsistent to have a charge-magnetic field interaction without a charge-charge Coulomb interaction. Moreover, a classical system of charges requires some hardcore or repulsive short-range interaction to be stable. Under such conditions, the system quickly equilibrates after the magnetic field interaction, and the claim that it is not at equilibrium is false.

@giorgiop,Well, let's take a look at this situation:
Using the technique of changing reference frames, we choose a rotating frame with an angular velocity of$-\frac{qB}{2m}$,It can be observed that in this frame, the force on the particle is analogous to the force arising from a potential field$V=\frac{q^2B^2r^2}{8m}$.In this frame, the system is expected to reach thermal equilibrium. However, when transformed back to the original frame, it is no longer in thermal equilibrium.

It seems that you want to neglect collisions or interparticle interactions. In such a case, it is not surprising that you may get a non-equilibrium macrostates.  You don't even need the magnetic field. `It is enough an ideal gas in a cubic box where all the particles start with velocities in the same direction parallel to two orthogonal walls. The system is not ergodic and you'll never get the Maxwell-Boltzmann velocity distribution.

Wow, I got it! It seems important to consider the contribution of interparticle interactions.@giorgio Thank you!



Why does the application of a magnetic field, an operation analogous to the evolution of the Hamiltonian, lead to non-thermodynamic equilibrium effects?


You did not specify which non-equilibrium effects you mean. Changing magnetic field is associated with presence of induced electric field. If the magnetic field is due to cylindrical electromagnet, even if it is quite  uniform, induced electric field won't be uniform, it will be almost zero on the axis of symmetry of the magnetic field source, and its strength will increase with distance from this axis. So acceleration effect of this electric field on charged particles, and thus also the heating effect, will be stronger near the walls than in the center of the container. This may cause non-equilibrium change in temperature in the system.
However, if the change of magnetic field is very slow, induced electric field will be negligible, and so will its heating effect and the resulting non-uniformity in temperature. In the limit $\dot{B}=0$, there is no non-equilibrium state, the system remains in equilibrium, and the process is quasi-static.


Are there any alternative methods to reach the same conclusion?


Alternative to what? To the above explanation?
I don't see what you meant by those formulae. A system obeying Boltzmann's statistics is in equilibrium, and it does not depend on value of magnetic field. A system of charged particles in container can plausibly be obeying Boltzmann statistics, due to collisions among particles and with walls of the container.
